# How To Use JavaScript To Copy Text From One Field To Another?

Tags: javascript, forms, input, copy, field

Is there any way to copy an inputs text value or field data to another field on the same page when the page first loads AUTOMATICALLY?

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Vague question is vague. Rejecting answers that don't guess it right is not the right approach, please provide more details.

Comment: Callum certainly gets it...not sure whats so difficult in my ?

Answer (score 0):

How about:
`document.getElementById('secondField').value = document.getElementById('firstField').value`

No JQuery =)

Comment: thanks...looks like this will work...but one ?  if the second field only has a name assign to the input and not an id, how would i do that?

Comment: what if i cant, will i not be able to do this?

Comment: dont have access to that part of the code im working with...trying to add functionality to a shopping cart in case ur wondering...

Comment: You could try using `document.getElementsByTagName` and finding the right one.

Comment: Actually, scratch that - use `document.getElementsByName`.

Comment: thanks for your feedback and guidence your certainly on the right path...but for some reason I cant get this to work? Maybe its bcuz i need to use an ID instead of name for the input not sure?

Comment: What's wrong with `document.getElementsByName('nameOfInput')[0].value`?

Comment: not sure maybe im not using the right name...im using the Firefox Firebug to see the name of the input i want to copy into.  Just to clarify the field Im trying to fill in is the input that has only a name and not an ID...the value I want to copy has an id.  Thanks again...

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$( 'input[name="fieldone"] ).val( $( 'input[name="fieldtwo"]' ).val() );
```

See http://api.jquery.com/val/ and http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/ for specifics.

Without using jQuery you can try (in supported browsers):

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[name$="fieldone"]').value = document.querySelectorAll('input[name$="fieldtwo"]').value;
```